# How to make events on CalendarDate in MUI-X v6

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Can someone teach me how to make events on my CalendarDate[Im stuck on here, I dont know how to use it in v6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BzPH.png)

I want to make events on my CalendarDate, but I dont know how to use slots and slotsProps. Please help me, Thankyou